# Missing Localized Screenshots Error on itunes

Tags: iphone, ios, binary, itunes

I have selected Default Language as "Australian English" as Default language. When I am submitting the binary it showing as rejected"Red Icon" with status "Missing Localized Screenshots". The application is in only single language. I have added screen shots also the application is only for iphone.

When I am looking binary information that is showing as:

Localizations :     ( "en-AU" )

Please suggest me where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Check if you have screenshots for iPhone 5. I had this same error, when screenshots for iP5 were missing.

Comment: Is this compulsory. As I have not make application for iPhone5. I mean screen size in my application is just for iPhone 4 and 4s.

Comment: If your app is messed up on iPhone5, make sure you didn't set a splash screen for iPhone 5 - once I removed it, and solved the problem for me and I got the app in a letterbox as needed

Comment: @Oded Ben Dov: Your answer solved my problem. Thank you very much. You could post this as a separate answer so someone would easily find it. Thanks.

Comment: Just for anyone who needs clarification, this is talking about the screenshots under the itunesconnect portal: https://itunesconnect.apple.com, not the iPhone 5 launch images that have to be compiled with the app. It took me a while to figure out that those were 2 different things.

Comment: This can also happen if you have a Universal app (e.g. PhoneGap!) and didn't include an iPad screenshot. Very confusing!

Comment: Upload iphone5 and iPad screen shots to itunesconnect.apple.com and this issue will be resolved...

Answer (score 10):

Basically the error telling you that **you need to upload the iPhone5 device screen shot**(at least one screen shot).

*So solution of the problem:*

**1.Either you can upload the screen shots for iPhone5 Device . OR**

**2.You can just removed the Default-568h.png from your binary , in this case your application just run in the "*letterbox*" mode on iPhone5 Device.**

So which ever is easy for you just adopt it .

I adopted the second one when i face the problem.

**HAPPY TO HELP**:):)

Comment: But with solution 1 there is always this little warning nagging me:  Missing "Default-568h@2x.png" launch image. Isn't there a way to say Xcode that I don't want to make an iPhone 5 app yet?

Comment: yes its showing an warning in xcode but its not have effect for you if you are not making app for iPhone5 specially,likely your app is run on iPhone5 as well in letter box mode.

Answer (score 4):

Just make sure to upload iPhone 5's screen shots .My app wasn't made for iphone 5 but I ran it on iphone 5 simulator and took screen shots and uploaded and every thing went ok.

Answer (score 2):

All above answers seems right, but this can happen too if you have NO screenshots for 3.5" - RETINA, beware.

Comment: yeah...this happened to me too

Answer (score 2):

If you already have screenshots for 3-in & 4-in, add a single screenshot for iPad and that should fix your problem.  The iPad shot is compulsory.

Answer (score 2):

Issue has been solved still posting may be it help someone. Please follow below steps:

1- Upload 5.5 inch display screenshots.

2- Click on "Device Manager".

3- Here you will have list of screen sizes with the options to expand on left side and a check box on right hand side "Use 5.5-Inch Display","Use 4.7-Inch Display".... and so on. Click on these checkboxes if you don't want to use different images than 5.5 inch display screenshots else upload new images here with correct dimensions.

4- Click save.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had the iPhone 5 (4" display) screenshots, but it also wanted 3.5" retina screenshots.

I added these, and the app went into 'Waiting for Review' state without further action.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, my solution was to change "Devices" in Development target only to iPhone (bacause i insert screens only for iPhone):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your app - you need to add the screenshots from the iTunes Connect metadata and uploads section.

Once I'd added these in all went through and the app won't automatically flagged as missing localized screenshots.

Not the best of messages, but not wildly inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and mine was a Universal iOS app made in GameSalad Creator, you need screenshots for all the relevant screens even if it lets you progress without them.

Answer (score 0):

I had changed the name of the app in the previous version and it choked on that. I changed the name of the app back to what it was and it went through fine..