# Localizations error in Dev Panel

Tags: ios, localization, app-store-connect

I purchased an app, attempted to update the info on the dev panel and when I try and save I'm receiving the following error

> There is an error for 1 of your localizations.

It shows the error location but I don't know what the issue is.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I am not sure if its related to programming? what is your code ?

Comment: Ensure that you have at lease one screenshot per device, filled description, keywords etc

Comment: @Panther I don't have the source code yet, only the transferred app (which is showing live).

Comment: @Azat The screenshots are all there for the devices, there is a description and the keyword is ".". Since this was transferred I cannot change the screenshots or keyword until I submit a new version. I'm  awaiting the source code to update... maybe that will fix it.

Comment: *I'm trying to update the copy write info which is set to the previous owner, when I change it and hit save is  when I get this error.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to write to the Apple support?

Comment: Hey go through my below [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38893874/4916161) may be it help you.

Comment: I had the same issue please go through my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38893874/4916161) may be it help you

Comment: Did you add keywords for the language as well? There are three mandatory fields: Description, What's New in This Version, and Keywords! Keywords cannot be added for a application that is in status "Ready for Sale", so you need to submit once again.

Answer (score 38):

This error can also occur if you have not deleted smaller, older size screen shots before checking the box in Media Manager to use new, larger screen size shots for that smaller size.

So if you are submitting a new version of an iPad app and you want your new 12.9 inch display screen shots to act as your 9.7 inch screen shots, you need to delete the **old** 9.7 inch screen shots before checking the box "Use 12.9-Inch Display."

Comment: Wow. Thanks. Apple is horrible.

Comment: saved my day, please mark this as the correct answer!

Comment: Thanks for that one.

Worse yet - we had no localizations, so all it said was: "There is an error on the page".

The localization dropdown was the only element lit up - and didn't have anything selected other than English (U.S.).  Thanks Apple!

Comment: Man you are genius and for God's sake, when I think Apple is a piece of crap developing web stuff they reach a new low. They should give up trying to do web stuff. Put a f* ftp server there and we upload all the media. Faster and easier.

Comment: May you live to be a thousand years old, sir! That solved a problem that I spent hours on!

Answer (score 4):

If you left any of the URLs empty, especially the Privacy Policy URL, then the Localization error appears. If you insert an URL, then the app may submit for review or else the Localization error shall disappear in the least. Please ensure that the URL is genuine, lest Apple delay or even reject the submission.

Comment: The Localization error usually occurs when an developer submits his or her app within the Kids' Category. The Privacy Policy URL is thus required. If the link is absent, then the Localization error appears.

Comment: If you do not want to bother with a Privacy Policy, do away with the Kids' Category in the Rating.

Comment: All url's are filled in.

Answer (score 3):

This message will appear if you have not provided a screen shot for every size iPhone and every size iPad (if you support iPad).  The fix is in the Media Manager and if you do not have a screen shot for some size device, check the option (to the right) to use another size screen shot for this size device.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue when trying to add a new localisation.

In my case, the problem appeared to be that the **Keywords** section was blank (and not even present on the UI, making it very difficult to realise what the problem was).

Apparently, to add/alter keywords, you need to upload a new binary. :-/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the localisation error "there is an error for 1 of your localizations" 
After googling the i came to know is that if you have missed any screen shots for ipad or iphone it will produce the same error 
Need to add the screen shots from here 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW3

Best Luck

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have at lease one screenshot per device. Just submit one set of screenshots and one optional app preview for the largest device size within a device family

Answer (score 0):

These days you get this error when screen shots for certain screen sizes are missing, which is misleading.
You could have largest screen/resolution screenshots and set the lower size/resolution screen shots to use those(there is a checkbox for this on the upper right corner of the pane) to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had two language localizations. Not sure how that happened. I deleted one and it worked. You have to follow the exclamation in the red circle. Wherever it is, your problem is.