# iTunesConnect : There are one or more errors on the page

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

[image]

I have already referred almost all other questions in `Stackoverflow`, But could not find the right solution.

I have been trying to fix this issue for a long time. `iTunesConnect` literally showing me this error, `There are one or more errors on the page`.

I am pretty sure that I didn't miss any of the required fields in `iTunesConnect`. The only fields which are left right now are these.

1. I have proper payment info & Availability.
2. I have proper screenshots & videos [ Both
       iPhone & iPad ] Only one set, all other options are empty.
3. Proper App Description, Keywords.
4. Proper Supporting URL, Marketing URL.
5. Proper Contact Information.
6. Proper Rating, Version Number, App Icon.
7. Proper Leaderboards, Muti-player functionality.
8. Proper Version Release info.
9. Proper App Information.
10. No need to worry about In App Purchase.
11. Proper Category.
12. Proper License Agreement.
13. Proper App Name and Privacy Policy URL.
14. Proper Build & Notes.

**Routing App Coverage File** -- It is an optional.
**Demo Account** -- My App does not need a demo account to test it out.

Did you guys face this issue? Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38960071/2669216)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by applying the new screenshots (for 5.5 inch) to all the other sizes. It could be done by MediaManager in the ScreenShot area. Hope it also works for you!

Comment: Is images the only reason cause in my case  there is red mark for Build ! all uploaded builds list should be displayed and need to select from those but build is showing no + symbol and when tried to upload using app-loader or xcode it says build already there

Comment: If I click Validate in Xcode while creating Archive and it's successful and furthermore when I click upload to app-store and it's say uploaded successfully does this mean that all my code signing and build steps are right ?

Comment: bty app previews is also must ??